# TrueCrypt создать контейнер из консоли в Windows?

Tags: windows, консоль, криптография

Добрый день...

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно из консоли Windows (bat файла в дальнейшем) создать раздел TrueCrypt(VeraCrypt)?
В Linux  все понятно

```
 truecrypt -c tcpfilepath
```

А в Windows (на 7 проверял) при вызове хелпа ключи только для монтирования и размонтирования.
Как-то ведь можно из консоли создавать? и автоматизировать...

Вот так  сейчас на линуксе - запуская скрипт, ввожу объем контейнера и все, остальное все expect  делаем. И так же хочу в Windows сделать.

Есть  какие варинты или там только через GUI?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае VeraCrypt (взято из [документации](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Command%20Line%20Usage)):

```
"C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\VeraCrypt Format.exe" /create c:\Data\test.hc /password test /hash sha512 /encryption serpent /filesystem FAT /size 10M /force
```